# stop recursion from 'deepest' reccursion in python 3

Tags: function, recursion, python-3.x

I am trying to stop errors happening in my code when an invalid input is entered by the user. Here is a simplified example that demonstrates my problem.

```
def foo():
try:
    a = int(input('1,2,3 or 4'))
except (ValueError, UnboundLocalError):
    print ('invalid input')
    print ('')
    print ('Try 1,2,3 or 4')
    foo()
if a == 3:
    print ('done')
```

When I input an intiger the function runs perfectly. When I input a string into the `a = int(input())` part it runs `foo()` again. However, when I then input 3 it prints `done'` but goes on to give as many `ValueError`'s as times I made an incorrect inputs followed by an `UnboundLocalError`.I think this is because im running the function over and over inside itself so it then has to 'come out' of this. Is there a better way to re run the function without using recursion? I am new to programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the last two lines inside the `try..except` block.

```
def foo():
    try:
        a = int(input('1,2,3 or 4'))
        if a == 3:
            print ('done')
    except (ValueError, UnboundLocalError):
        print ('invalid input')
        print ('')
        print ('Try 1,2,3 or 4')
        foo()
```

And you'd better use `while` loop to avoid increasing the recursion depth:

```
def foo():
    while True:
        try:
            a = int(input('1,2,3 or 4'))
            if a == 3:
                print ('done')
            break
        except (ValueError, UnboundLocalError):
            print ('invalid input')
            print ('')
            print ('Try 1,2,3 or 4')
```

Answer (score 0):

Pull the try and except block outside of your recursive function This way you don't enter multiple different trys. Then when your recursive function throws an error, it'll go all the way back up it that one any only try block that you have.

Comment: does 'catch' mean 'except'? could you post what you mean in code? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're having is that you don't exit the function when you recurse in your exception handler. One solution would be to `return foo()` when you recurse, but this is still going to be awkward (Python doesn't do tail call optimization, so this will build up a big stack of calls waiting to be returned from, if you keep entering invalid values). A better solution is to use a loop:

```
a=None:
while a is None:
    try:
        a = int(input('1,2,3 or 4'))
    except ValueError:
        print ('invalid input')
        print ('')
        print ('Try 1,2,3 or 4')
    # you could do more validation here, and set `a` back to `None` if it is invalid
if a == 3:
    print("done")
```

The `while` loop will keep on asking for input until an acceptable value is provided by the user. No recursion is needed.